# How to make csplit start outputing files with filenames starting from 001?

Tags: csplit

I use csplit to divide a complex file named `file.docked.pdb` to small files.

```
csplit -k -s -n 3 -f file.docked. file.docked.pdb '/^ENDMDL/+1' '{'7'}'
```

`man csplit` explains the following the code perfectly

```
NAME
       csplit - split a file into sections determined by context lines


       -k, --keep-files
              do not remove output files on errors

      -s, --quiet, --silent
              do not print counts of output file sizes
      -n, --digits=DIGITS
              use specified number of digits instead of 2

       -f, --prefix=PREFIX
              use PREFIX instead of 'xx'

   Each PATTERN may be:


       /REGEXP/[OFFSET]
              copy up to but not including a matching line

       {*}    repeat the previous pattern as many times as possible
```

My doubt is that the output files are starting to be named from `file.docked.000` and extending forward

How to make the numbering start from `file.docked.001`???

If the tooling does not support this at all, please give a workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index of the first file output file is always 0 and there is no option to change the start index.

As a workaround, you could use a process substitution to print your pattern once before your data is output. This way this dummy line is split into file `file.docked.000` which you can delete afterwards.
Also increase the repeat pattern by one to get the desired number of output files.

```
csplit -k -s -n 3 -f file.docked. \
  <(echo "ENDMDL dummy, delete this file"; cat file.docked.pdb) '/^ENDMDL/+1' '{8}' &&
  rm file.docked.000
```